# Please somebody tell me how we can create this kind of behavior? And what we called this behavior?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

Before collapse

[image]

After collapse

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that :

The demo :
https://codyhouse.co/demo/horizontal-timeline/index.html

The code :
https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/

I think it can be a solution. This is made with jquery.
Not sure that you can do it only in CSS

Comment: Thank you very much @jean-maxime. Yeah it's working.But it's very hard to place in website,there are so much code.If you have something similar to this in easy way plzzz tell me.

Comment: can u please tell me,how http://www.apple.com/in/ipad/   they placed text near to picture.please help me..!!

Comment: @AnkitJain Use developer tool on your navigator to see it !